# vb.net and transactionscope

Tags: sql, vb.net

I inherited a bunch of vb.net code at work.  A pattern that I see throughout the many apps that the previous guy wrote follows.  What I'm wondering is how reliable/safe this is to run across console/winforms/asp.net applications?  Do the options he sets make sense?  Why isn't there a rollback in the catch block?  If I go for a big re-factoring effort should I change this or deal with the many other more pressing and obvious issues first?

He has a small class:

```
Public Class TransactionUtils

    Public Shared Function CreateTransactionScope() As TransactionScope
        Dim transactionOptions = New TransactionOptions()
        transactionOptions.IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted
        transactionOptions.Timeout = TransactionManager.MaximumTimeout
        Return New TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, transactionOptions)
    End Function

End Class
```

Then whenever he adds records to more than one table or DB, it's something like this:

```
Dim scope As TransactionScope = TransactionUtils.CreateTransactionScope()

        Try

            Using scope

                Using connection1 As New SqlConnection(SqlConnectString)

                    connection1.Open()

                    Dim SQCMD As New SqlCommand

                    SQCMD.Connection = connection1

                    SQCMD.Parameters.Clear()

                    SQCMD.Parameters.Add("@PKEY", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 8
                    SQCMD.Parameters.Add("@L001", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = 1.8
                    SQCMD.Parameters.Add("@CTEMP", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = 1.8
                    SQCMD.Parameters.Add("@BKW", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = 1

                    SQCMD.Parameters.Add("@MSG", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 250).Value = "Test4"
                    SQCMD.Parameters.Add("@ENUM", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 4.5


                    SQCMD.CommandText = "INSERT INTO MSGLOG (MSG,ENUM) VALUES (@MSG,@ENUM)"

                    returnValue = SQCMD.ExecuteNonQuery()

                    SQCMD.CommandText = "INSERT INTO MDATA (PKEY,L001,CTEMP,BKW) VALUES (@PKEY,@L001,@CTEMP,@BKW)"

                    returnValue = SQCMD.ExecuteNonQuery()

                End Using

                scope.Complete()

            End Using

        Catch ex As Exception
            'Some error action
        End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

He's not running a transaction like you're thinking, he's setting, and possibly overriding a default, transaction isolation level in the database. [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189122(v=sql.105).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189122%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) I see it as safe, but I've NEVER seen anyone use this before. I can only imagine that the database default isolation level was goofy, or that he was maybe instrumenting the code so that he could easily change a block of code to run in read UNcommitted. You should look around your environment to see if you can see a reason.

Comment: I see what you are saying, it looks like he got the idea to set those options here: [link]http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dbrowne/archive/2010/05/21/using-new-transactionscope-considered-harmful.aspx[/link]

Comment: Your link broke, if you can edit it to fix. I see the page you're talking about however. Well, now you have the context anyhow.